# .NET Web Api UserManagerExtensions.ConfirmEmail

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to pass in the userId and the code/token i've generated when the user confirms their registration via their email.

I'm fairly new to c# and cant figure out how I can pass these values into the UserManagerExtensions.ConfirmEmail method.

Here is my current code:

```
public class EmailController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ConfirmEmail")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Id and Code are required");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManagerExtensions.ConfirmEmail(userId, code);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't like me passing in the userId as a string! Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Hey, did your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using attribute routing, you need to pass it in a Url; hence change your route as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ConfirmEmail/{userId}/{code}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
}
```

Now your URL would be `/Email/ConfirmEmail/userId/code`.